# Python ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have the code below, where the input is `h_ply =['0.12, 0.15, 0.2, 0.125']`

```
h_ply = simpledialog.askstring('Laminate Properties','Ply Thickness')
try:
    h_layer_list = [int(x) for x in h_ply.split(',')] 
    h_layer = np.array(h_layer_list) * 0.001
```

I have also tried

```
h_ply1 = np.array(h_ply)
h_layer = h_ply1.astype(np.float)
```

But got the same error.

I am trying to get `h_ply` list into a `np.array` of Floats. But a ValueError appears.
I understand this could be because I should have `''` every number and not just at the ends? But ideally I want to avoid that to be more user friendly. What is the best way to get rid of this Error message?

Thank you

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to deal with this is to properly access the string.  Look at your data:

```
h_ply =(       # a tuple, containing ...
         [     # a single element, a list, containing ...
           [   # a single element, a list, containing ...
             '0.12, 0.15, 0.2, 0.125'     # ... a string that you have to split
           ]
         ]
       )
```

You have to peel off all of those layers to get to the string:

```
h_str = h_ply[0][0][0]
```

*Now* you can split the string and convert the elements to numeric values.  The code you posted is trying to split the tuple and convert it.

Comment: Just to be sure, I should strip it to `h_ply =['0.12, 0.15, 0.2, 0.125']` and then it should work?

Comment: No, you have to strip it to the string.

Comment: I am really sorry, I am new to Python, so I am not following very well. Could you give an example, please?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  I *did* give you an example.  If you do not understand the differences among these data structures, then we need you to go back to your educational materials.  Individual tutoring is out of scope for Stack Overflow.